# using include_blank in f.select but not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use dropdown to list all my projects and the first option is blank.

but when I add :include_blank => true, it doesn't work.

just like that:

```
<%= f.select(:project_id, :include_blank => true) do %>
  <% @projects.each do |p| %>
    <%= content_tag(:option, p.name, value: p.id) %>
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

but if I use

```
<%= f.select(:title, %w{ Male Female }, :include_blank => true) %>
```

It works exactly!
I don't know how to revise the first code to make the blank appear.

Thanks!

Comment: try `<%= f.select :category_id, nil, :include_blank => true %>`

Comment: Thx a lot !! it exactly work!! but why? is it about the second arguement?

Comment: Look at the docs. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select. The second argument is expecting a method

Comment: This is the method call being used (the first argument is `method`): http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `<%= content_tag … %>`. Try this:

```
<%= f.select(:project_id, :include_blank => true) do
  @projects.each do |p|
    content_tag(:option, p.name, value: p.id)
  end
end %>
```

(ie. just a single ERB output embedding tag)

Update: looking over this again, you are not really customising the way the options are generated, do you really need the block?

```
<%= f.select(:project_id, @projects.collect { |p| [p.name, p.id] }, :include_blank => true) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
<%= f.select :category_id, nil, :include_blank => true %>
```

In the documention API [LINK](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select)

`select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)`

Comment: Wrong API method, it's this one: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select . The signature is `select(method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)`

Comment: The original usage from the question `f.select(:project_id, :include_blank => true) do … end` is (at a high level) valid.

Answer (score 0):

U can do this:

```
<%= f.select(:project, :id, @projects.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {:include_blank => true}) %>
```

Or

```
<%= f.select(:project_id, @projects.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {:include_blank => true}) %>
```

Or you can use prompt:

```
<%= f.select(:project, :id, @projects.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {:prompt => 'select project'}) %>
```